# Is there an easy one liner to convert a text file to a dictionary in Python without using CSV?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text

I have a 10,000 line file called "number_file" like this with four columns of numbers.

```
12123 12312321 12312312 12312312
12123 12312321 12312312 12312312
12123 12312321 12312312 12312312
12123 12312321 12312312 12312312
```

I need to convert the file to a dictionary where the first column numbers are the keys and the entire line are the values

So far, I tried this but it didn't work.

```
dict((line.strip().split('\t')[0] for line in file(number_file)))
```

How do I fix this one liner so that it converts the file to a dictionary?

Comment: are you doing this to remove duplicates? You could use a set if you are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following dict comprehension:

```
with open(number_file) as fileobj:
    result = {row[0]: row[1:] for line in fileobj for row in (line.split(),)}
```

where the `for row in (one_element_tuple,)` is effectively an assignment.

Or you could use a nested generator expression to handle the splitting of each line:

```
with open(number_file) as fileobj:
    result = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in (line.split() for line in fileobj)}
```

However, if your file is really tab-delimited, don't fear the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open(number_file) as fileobj:
    result = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter='\t')}
```

Comment: @MrDoe777: how did you test that? Take into account that your OS will have cached the file after reading it the first time.

Comment: Ran them both after caching

Answer (score 1):

`split()` takes a *maxsplit* argument that limits how many times to split the string.

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    data = dict(line.strip().split(maxsplit=1) for line in f)
```